# Something wrong with mailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, smtp, actionmailer

I configured mailer in my rails app. And send test email from localhost and everything works fine. But if I try to edit my mailer view, mailer dont work(`Timeout::Error at ... execution expired`). And even restarting the server does not solve the problem.

The problem is solved only reboot. But after reboot it all over again. Everything work fine but one view correction and only reboot again.

Mailer config:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.yandex.ru",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "yandex.ru",
  :user_name            => "user@name.com",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true }

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

Ubuntu 12.04

Ruby 1.9.3-p327

Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have some firewall related issues. To check that - try testing email server connection throuh `telnet`- http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/03/15/Troubleshooting-email%5F2C00%5F-the-Telnet-way.aspx